# Hotkeys disable Debian 10

Tags: debian, hotkeys, debian-buster, global-hotkey

I have Debian based linux and i need to disable hotkeys. Once upon a time i found working advice for hotkeys disable, but i lost it. In advice was something like this:

1. Create separate config file
2. Add section with containth "Disable" = hotkeys

Maybe someone can understand what is this and how to use it?

I have one working way:
I commented global config "; include /usr/share/fly-wm/keyshortcutrc"
And then i commented hotkeys in local config. But i can disable only exist hotkeys normally. When i try to disable browser hotkeys, for example "Ctrl+N", i need to add in local config file string 'Ctrl|n = "true"'. After that "Ctrl+N" stopped working but when i pressed "Ctrl+N" during using browser, then mouse cursor type changed to "wait" type.
I need to disable hotkeys absolutely, so that the system does not react in any way to their use